# How do I extract the value attribute of <input> into a variable?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a list of Property_Rate__c records in an Apex:repeat function. For every record in the list, a checkbox is created. The value attribute of each checkbox is the ID of the Property_Rate__c record. I am wondering: When one of the checkboxes is checked, how to extract the ID value into a variable for later use?

```
<apex:repeat value="{!property_rate_list}" var="propertyRate" id="propertyRateList">

    <input type="checkbox" value="{!propertyRate.Id}" class="dateCheckbox" onchange="verifyChecked($(this));" />

</apex:repeat>
```

verfiyChecked Function

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict()   
    function verifyChecked(checkbox)
    {
        $('.dateCheckbox:checked').prop('checked', false); // clear all checkboxes
        $(checkbox).prop('checked', !$(checkbox).prop('checked')); // toggle
        //changeDate($(checkbox).val());
    }
```

Comment: I think you need that inside javascript isn't it ? if yes you can easily do that using .prop method in javascript.

Comment: I've used javascript to toggle the checkboxes so that only one is selected at once. Can you also save the value into a variable using js? @Himanshu

Comment: you can modify your onchange function as onchange ="verifyChecked($(this),'{!propertyRate.Id}');" function and get value inside javascript.

Comment: So that's what I'm wondering how to do. How do I get the value from the checkbox using javascript and save that into an apex ID variable? @Himanshu

Comment: I assume with my last comment you can get propertyRate id in javascript and from javascript you can use apex:actionfunction to set variable in apex code. understood ?

Comment: Would you mind giving an example/answer of the javascript that gets the propertyRate Id? Also could you include how to pass the javascript variable into apex:actionfunction? @Himanshu

Comment: please update your question with your verifyChecked function code. I will surely help you to guide you for rest of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are going to use **[actionfucntion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm)** to pass value from visaulforce to controller.

I have defined inline comments. I hope it will help you to understand the code.

HTML update

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{!propertyRate.Id}" 
class="dateCheckbox" onchange="return verifyChecked($(this),'{!propertyRate.Id}');" />
```

Javascript update

```
function verifyChecked(checkbox,recordid)
{

    $('.dateCheckbox:checked').prop('checked', false); // clear all property 
     checkboxes
    $(checkbox).prop('checked', !$(checkbox).prop('checked')); // toggle
    //changeDate($(checkbox).val());
    //call action function.
    callmethod(recordid);
    return false;
}
```

Add following code before apex:form closing tag

```
 <!-- This code will call actionfunction and pass the value to controller -->
 <apex:actionfunction name="callmethod" action="{!setProperty}" status="updatestatus">
     <apex:param name="propertyid" value=""/>
</apex:actionfunction>
<apex:actionstatus id="updatestatus" starttext="updating.." stoptext=""/>
```

Controller method

```
public void setProperty()
{
     //read propertyid value from page.
     String propertyid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('propertyid');

     //user this propertyId for your logic.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is broken down very clearly. I have one question though: When you use callmethod(recordId) in javascript, this calls the apex:actionfunction. Within the apex:param, the name is "propertyId", and the value is blank. How does the controller method end up getting the ID when it "gets" the name? Should it not get blank ("")?

Comment: no it will not be blank. when I call callmethod(recordid) it map the value with apex:param propertyid. :)

this is the way it works :)

Comment: Interesting...You have been very helpful. Thank you! Would you have any idea why when I try System.debug(propertyId) at the end of the controller method, I am getting null instead of the ID?

Comment: try to alert recordid value prior to callmethod in js to make sure you are getting property id value.

Comment: Yep that is working fine!

Comment: I have mis spelled proertyid while defining it. please check.

Comment: Yep I caught that too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31319/discussion-between-himanshu-and-alex-brigham).